# Fraud Detection with Apache Flink , Kubernetes on DCOS 1.11

Tags: kubernetes, dcos

Trying out this DCOS 1.11 demo on **AWS** with 4 private agents and 1 public agents, all m4.xlarge . 
https://github.com/dcos/demos/tree/master/flink-k8s/1.11 
Was able to install all using **dcos-cli** on my **windows laptop**, but when it come to configuring K8s, the following step is not very clear :
 "dcos kubernetes kubeconfig" 
 turns out the above command is missing additional params, so refered the following docs 
https://docs.mesosphere.com/services/kubernetes/1.1.1-1.10.4/exposing-the-kubernetes-api/ 
 https://docs.mesosphere.com/services/kubernetes/1.1.1-1.10.4/connecting-clients/  
 Still not working. 
 Couple of notes : 
 used the Public IP of my dcos-public-agent (ec2 instance) in the command below 
https://35.227.190.217:6443 --insecure-skip-tls-verify 
Also trying to 
 reach the Kubernetes API using the below command
curl -k https://35.227.190.217:6443 
 yields a http 401 error response and not 403 as indicated in the documentation. 
 Wondering if there is a clear documentation somewhere or has anyone been able to configure k8s with DCOS CE. Please help.

Comment: Did you already configured [kubectl](https://docs.mesosphere.com/services/kubernetes/1.0.2-1.9.6/connecting-clients/)?

Comment: Hi, which DC/OS kubernetes version are you using? The behavior has changed with the latest release of that package (so the instructions in the demo should still work for an older version of that package). https://docs.mesosphere.com/services/kubernetes/1.1.1-1.10.4/exposing-the-kubernetes-api/  looks like the right link, what issues are you facing here?